# c# Replace default New/Edit/Disp webparts for SharePoint list items

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Currently I have a sharepoint solution containing custom webparts for a sharepoint list's New/Edit/Disp forms. As of now, I point the list at these webparts by manually navigating to these pages and inserting them via the gui. My question now is, how do I automate this process via C#? Is it possible to replace the default list item forms with my own custom webparts? My attempt is below, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8430676/2596756) link.

I have created an event receiver to handle this

Code:

```
    public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite sp_Site = new SPSite("http://root/site/Lists"))
        {
            string err = string.Empty;
            using (SPWeb sp_Web = sp_Site.OpenWeb())
            {
                XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(sp_Web.GetFileAsString("http://root/_catalogs/wp/myWebPart.webpart")));
                SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = sp_Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("http://root/site/Lists/MyList/DispForm.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

                WebPart wp = (WebPart)wpm.ImportWebPart(reader, out err);
                wpm.AddWebPart(wp, "Main", 0);
                wpm.SaveChanges(wp);
            }
        }
```

I can't currently debug this because the error `Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>`

Am I doing this correctly? Is there another way? Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not overriding the correct event in this case.

Try to override FeatureActivated instead, as the web parts only become available once the feature has been activated.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    // do stuff  
}
```

If you still experience the error you mentioned while deploying your solution, try the following:

- close visual studio
- restart the "Sharepoint 2010 User Code Host" service
- restart the "Windows Management Instrumentation" service
- open visual studio and try to deploy your solution again